# Pivot query not working

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to show the year as column and salesamount below it.

This query shows OrderYear and then subtotal:

```
Select YEAR(OrderDate) As OrderYear, SUM(SubTotal) as OrderTotal
    From Sales.SalesOrderHeader s
        Group by YEAR(OrderDate)
```

So I had to write a pivot query for it. This is my pivot query which is not working:

```
Select [2001] , [2002], [2003], [2004]
From
(
    Select YEAR(OrderDate) As OrderYear, SUM(SubTotal) as OrderTotal
    From Sales.SalesOrderHeader s
        Group by YEAR(OrderDate)    
) a
Pivot(
    OrderTotal FOR OrderYear In ([2001] , [2002], [2003], [2004])
) pvt
```

Can anybody spot the mistake? I am using AdventureWorks sample database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an aggregate.

This is still required by the syntax even if you only expect there to be only one value ever being aggregated (in which case either `MAX` or `MIN` will do)

```
MAX(OrderTotal) FOR OrderYear In ([2001] , [2002], [2003], [2004])
```

Though actually in your case you don't need the inner aggregation and can use

```
Select [2001] , [2002], [2003], [2004]
From
(
    Select YEAR(OrderDate) As OrderYear, SubTotal
    From Sales.SalesOrderHeader s  
) a
Pivot(
    SUM(SubTotal) FOR OrderYear In ([2001] , [2002], [2003], [2004])
) pvt
```